# Forms of foregrounding: are recurrence / equivalence the same?

Tags: terminology, literary-device, literary-criticism

I'm struggling to grasp the difference between the literary devices of recurrence and equivalence. I'm preparing for an exam where we are asked to define these terms. In German, they are referred to as "Rekurrenz / Äquivalenz".

In my understanding so far, both are a form of *foregrounded regularity* (Giving unusual prominence to a "regular element" of a text).

Can anyone give me some examples of Recurrence and Equivalence in literary texts?